# How can I keep correct size of Bootstrap alerts while using jQuery UI effects?

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to keep the proper size of the Bootstrap alert during a jQuery UI effect, like "shake".

What seems to be happening is that during the effect the div containing the alert gets a *new height and width style* applied that are smaller than they should be.  Once the effect is complete everything looks normal again.

Any thoughts?

[Fiddle me this](http://jsfiddle.net/wphampton/a3qdwdfw/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        // or try "bounce", "slide", "drop"...probably others.
        $( ".alert" ).effect( "shake" );
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have something to do with `box-sizing: border-box` changing this to `box-sizing: content-box` seems to resolve the issue. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/9277qu4f/)

```
.alert {
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
}
```

There are a few other work-arounds listed in the links below...

[Bug logged with jQuery UI](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8867)

[Related Question from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301972/jquery-ui-shake-padding-disappears)